# перезагрузка VOSK

Tags: python, vosk

```
    import importlib    
def reloadmodule():
        importlib.reload(vosk)
```

при загрузке программы грузится модуль VOSK и его модель языка
такой метод не работает для перезагрузки моделя тоесть смены языка
как это можно сделать?

Comment: Где у вас там vosk импортируется? Модель настраивается и ни чего общего с импортом vosk не имеет. Удалите предыдущую модель (если память не позволяет две одновреммено открыть) и загрузите новую. Покажите как вы используете vosk,  а не то как вы его хотите импортировать.

Comment: Добавить нужно в вопрос, соблюдая  форматирование.

Comment: это ответить на собственный вопрос?, а уже нешел где, код исправил

Comment: Нет не ответить на вопрос а добавить в текущий вопрос код, который демонстрирует проблему.Чем больше информации тем лучше.

Comment: сделать переменную rec глобальной. в функции "перезагрузки" менять её значение и выгружать старую модель.